# sed: replace two or more tabs with one

Tags: replace, terminal

I would like to replace double or more tabs in a string with one using sed. However, when I do

> echo "A\t\tB\t\tC" | sed  's/\t\t/\t/g'

I get the same thing back

> A\t\tB\t\tC

How can I get this?

> A\tB\tC

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already got it - you just missed a flag to echo => `-e`

```
$ echo -e "A\t\tB\t\tC" | sed -e 's/\t\t/\t/g'
A   B   C

$ echo -e "A\t\tB\t\tC" 
A       B       C
```

Update: don't forget the -e on sed!

Comment: That does not do it though for me...

`echo -e "A\t\tB\tC" | sed  's/\t\t/\t/g'` i get still

`A  B C` with two tabs between A B and only one between B C

Comment: That would imply that, for you, there is there no difference between `echo -e "A\t\tB\tC"` and `echo -e "A\t\tB\tC" | sed s/\t\t/\t/g`?  Could you check?  (Their output is different and working as expected for my terminals)

Comment: As strange as it may be, there is indeed no difference between outputs for me... I am using a mac with bash 3.2.51(1)-release.

Comment: Whoops, typo on sed - it's missing the `-e` =>  `sed -e 's/\t\t/\t/g'`

Comment: Still a no for me... output stayed the same with sed -e.